# Get console parameters in ISuite class (TestNG)

Tags: java, testng

I´m writting a new listener to open and close the database connection at start and end of the suite. I defined several parameters in the testng.xml file to store the database credentials, for example:

```
<parameter name="DB.user" value="user"/>
```

Now, I´m trying to get this parameters in the listener:

```
public class DatabaseListener implements ISuiteListener {
@Override
public void onStart(ISuite suite) {

    System.out.println( suite.getXmlSuite().getParameter("DB.user"));
}
```

This works fine, but I also need this parameters will be updated if I overwrite the value by command line:

```
-DDB.user=test
```

I´m always getting the value defined in the testng.xml (user) instead the value I set in console (test).

For example, in a test I do the next to get the runtime value:

```
@BeforeClass()
@Parameters({"DB.user"})
public void beforeClass(String DBUser)
```

How can I do this in the listener?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG is capable of updating `<parameters>` by using their names and then overriding their values with the values provided via JVM arguments (`-D`). But that happens at a much later stage and well before an actual `@Test` method is invoked.

But its not true when TestNG is invoking suite level listeners, which is what you are doing. At this point, TestNG is still just constructing the suite file and the above mentioned parameter value resolution is yet to happen. That explains why you always see the value that is present in the suite file.

One way of dealing with this would be to do the following:

```java
public class DatabaseListener implements ISuiteListener {
@Override
public void onStart(ISuite suite) {

    String fromSuite = suite.getXmlSuite().getParameter("DB.user");
    String parameter = System.getProperty("DB.user", fromSuite);
    System.out.println( parameter);
}
```

As you can see, you are explicitly querying from the System properties and at the same time defining a default value which comes from your suite. Kind of works the same way as TestNG resolves parameters (but at a later stage)

Comment: Thanks you! Very good explanation. This solve my question.

Comment: An expert answer, this solved one of my requirements too.